# Browser is not launching even test is running through Jenkins on ubuntu

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am trying to launch browser for automation testing(selenium) using jenkins on ubuntu OS. Test are running properly but browser is not launching seems like it is running headlessly.

I am able to fix this using this solution -

- Added Xvfb plugin and added DISPLAY variable.
- Running jenkins.war
     from console using *java -jar jenkins.war*

As I know in Windows OS by checking **"Allow service to interact with desktop"** while jenkins installation we can fix this. So Is there any way we can do this on ubuntu by updating some configuration so we don't have run jenkins.war from console everytime.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to facilitate the launch of browser on ubuntu OS.

1.First way - Configure your Jenkins nodes and add the ubuntu machine. Add the sshing details(username-password OR RSA key) of the target machine. This configuration is recommended if you are in cloud.

2.Second way(not recommended on cloud environments) -You have to run a Selenium standalone-Server (a standalone node), and register your remote WebDriver to it.

```
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://ipOfUbuntuMachine:port/wd/hub"), capability);
```